# Kotlin: Inline lambda and overload resolution ambiguity

Tags: lambda, kotlin, overload-resolution

I have a simple factory pattern where the implementation is determined through overload resolution. Problem is that the Kotlin compiler complains with "Overload resolution ambiguity.." for the inline lambda.

```
class Foo(){
    companion object Factory {
        fun create(x: Int, f: (Int) -> Double) = 2.0
        fun create(x: Int, f: (Int) -> Int) = 1
    }
}

fun main(args:Array<String>){
    val a =  Foo.create(1,::fromDouble) //OK
    val b =  Foo.create(1,::fromInt)  //OK
    val ambiguous =  Foo.create(1){i -> 1.0}  //Overload resolution ambiguity?
}


fun fromDouble(int:Int)  = 1.0
fun fromInt(int:Int)  = 1
```

How does the Kotlin compiler resolve overload resolution and why is the inline lambda considered to be ambiguous?

Comment: This seems to be a bug, because if I cast the lambda like `{ i: Int -> 1.0 } as (Int) -> Double` there's no ambiguity, but it says that cast is not needed. Also, if I extract the lambda to `val l = { i: Int -> 1.0 }` and use it, again there's no ambiguity. Please search the bug tracker for this issue and if it's not there file a new one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: Another interesting thing is if you cast the lambda as @hotkey does, the IDE will tell you that it's not necessary.  But the moment you remove it, it complains about ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Figured that it probably was a bug. Filed a report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11265

Comment: This still seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin compiler resolves every expression only once.
So when compiler starts resolution for lambda expression, it should know types of lambda arguments.
Because of this compiler should choose one of methods `create` ***before*** it starts to look inside lambda.

Example:

```
fun foo(f: (Int) -> Int) = 1
fun foo(f: (String) -> String) = ""
val bar = foo { 
   println(it) 
   5
}
```

Here we can't choose one of functions `foo` because no one of them is  more specific that another, so we can't start resolution for lambda expression  because we don't know type for `it`.

In your example it is in theory possible to start resolution for lambda before choosing particular function because for all potential functions types of lambda arguments are the same. But it is untrivial logic which might be hard to implement.

Comment: That's a bummer. Overload resolution on lambda is a very usefull for numerical application. Let say I have a matrix class that work on float, double and int. With "overload resolution" instancing would be  `val ms = Mat44{i,j -> 1.0}` , now I'm forced to write `val ms = Mat44({i:Int,j:Int -> 1.0} as (Int,Int) -> Double )` which is just plain and silly verbose for such a trivial task.  Many thanks @erokhins for a great explanation!

Comment: As workaround you can create functions with different names: `fun Mat44Int2Double(f: (Int, Int) -> Double) = Mat44(f)`. But it isn't elegant...

Comment: This same issue also applies for lambdas in constructors. You'll get an overload ambiguity as well.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running into this in 2023, there is a workaround to make Kotlin look at lambda return types when resolving overloads (which it normally doesn't do).

As shown [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38962/Overload-resolution-ambiguity-for-functions-with-lambda-parameter-returns-different-types#focus=Comments-27-4181061.0-0), you must opt in to experimental type inference and annotate the methods accordingly:

```kotlin
import kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalTypeInference

@OptIn(ExperimentalTypeInference::class) // Can be done per method, class or file
@OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType
fun bar(f: () -> Int): String {
    return "${f()}"
}

fun bar(f: () -> String): String {
    return f()
}

fun main() {
    println(
        bar {
            3
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in case there's a relationship between the return types. If I change the first fun to `fun bar(f: () -> Any): String` then the example no longer compiles. Do you know if there's a solution to that?